# Wordpress "sub-homepages"

Tags: wordpress

My Wordpress 3.5 website currently has a few hundred posts in varying categories. The problem we've got now is that we've got so much content we would like to create sub-homepages for each section.

So for example we currently have this structure:

```
Home
-- Category 1
---- Sub category 1
---- Sub category 2
---- Sub category 3
-- Category 2
---- Sub category 1
---- Sub category 2
---- Sub category 3
```

We would like to keep this structure, but when clicking on category 1 or category 2 from the main homepage, it then displays a sub-homepage with content managed buttons for each of the sub categories underneath it. Making it easier for our users to drill down to the content they're looking for.

I assume I need to make a custom template of sorts (for the sub-homepage), but was hoping someone could point me in the right direction to achieving this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function page is a good resource for what you're trying to do:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories

Your template file would be

- `category-{slug}.php` (where slug/id is that of the category tag) or
- `category-{id}.php` and if none of these exist, it falls back to:
- `category.php`

If you organize your categories using taxonomies, you can use custom taxonomy templates, like:

- `taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php`, so you would have:
- `taxonomy-cars-audi.php`
- `taxonomy-cars-porche.php`
- `taxonomy-planets-mars.php`
- `taxonomy-planets-jupiter.php`

See here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Category_display

**Navigation**

The question you have in terms of navigation:  Do you want all `cars` terms, and any newly added terms, to automatically show up in your menu?  If so, you can display all taxonomy terms using `wp_list_categories()`, and you'll need to pass in some arguments to show the correct taxonomy.  See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories for more info on that.

Your other option is to create a custom menu, using the built in /wp-admin/ menu creator.  This would allow you to pick and choose which terms to show in the list, however you'd have to manually remove terms and add new terms.

**URL Structure**

Another decision:  What do you want your URL structure to look like?  If you want `mysite.com/cars/audi/` to show all your audi posts, then the default taxonomy template file (`taxonomy-cars-audi.php`) will work fine.

If, however, you want a custom url, like `mysite.com/best-cars-ever/`, then you'd need to create a custom page template, and link it to that page.